# textContent object property doesn't work

Tags: javascript, loops, object, innerhtml

```
var container = document.getElementById("grid-container");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var div;
var reuqest;

function HTTPRequest(url) {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', url);
        request.onload = function() {
            result(request);            
        };
        request.send();
}

function result(data){
        var res = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
        var array = res.results;
        var myObj = array[0];
        console.log(myObj);
        for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(myObj).length; i++) {
            div = document.createElement("div");
            div.className = "grid-item";
            container.appendChild(div); 
            for (let key in myObj) {
                console.log(myObj[key]);
                div.textContent = myObj[key];
            }
        }   
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    HTTPRequest('https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson','author');
});
```

I am trying to loop through all properties of the object and give the divs I created the text content of each property of the object above.

For some reason I get:

true instead of "track", "song" etc...

Do you know why?

Thanks

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Each iteration of the loop is reassigning `textContent` completely, replacing any text that was previously set. It seems likely the last value the loop visits from `myObj` is a boolean. Perhaps use `+=` to concatenate the values together.

Comment: do you want all values concatenated in div, or give each value in obj to each div?

Comment: @RonnWilder I would like each property value to populate each div but I know as it is set now it repeats to each div

Answer (score 1):

Update the [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) of div like this instead of `textContent` and also change `=` operator to `+=`.

```js
var myObj = {
  wrapperType: "track",
  kind: "song",
  artistId: 909253,
  collectionId: 879273552,
  trackId: 879273565
}

var div = document.getElementById("test");
var content = ""
for (let key in myObj) {
  content += key + ": " + myObj[key] + "<br>";
}

div.innerHTML = content;
```

```html
<div id="test">It is a test</div>
```

---

Instead of `for(let ... in ...)` you can use this (According to @Jonathan-Lonowski's answer)

```js
let myObj = {
  wrapperType: "track",
  kind: "song",
  artistId: 909253,
  collectionId: 879273552,
  trackId: 879273565
},
container = document.getElementById("container");

Object.entries(myObj).forEach(function(itm) {
  div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "grid-item";
  container.appendChild(div);
  div.textContent = itm[0] + ": " + itm[1];
});
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to append a `div` for each of `myObj`'s keys/values, then it should be unnecessary to use two loops to iterate through the keys.

Saving the list of `keys` from `myObj` that the `for` loop is iterating over…

```
var keys = Object.keys(myObj);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

You can get the `key` for each iteration using the index, `i`, without needing the additional `for..in` loop:

```
var key = keys[i];
div.textContent = myObj[key];
```

Combined:

```
function result(data){
    var res = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
    var array = res.results;
    var myObj = array[0];
    var keys = Object.keys(myObj);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var key = keys[i];
        div = document.createElement("div");
        div.className = "grid-item";
        div.textContent = myObj[key];
        container.appendChild(div);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. for (let key in myObj) {
    div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "grid-item";
    container.appendChild(div); 
      console.log(myObj[key]);
      div.textContent = myObj[key];
   }

Comment: As you all suggested, I've created the divs for each key and then add them the values of the properties. Thank you all for helping

Answer (score 1):

**The last `key-value` pair of every object from that response is:**

```
"isStreamable":true
```

Therefore, when you're assigning a value to that div as follow `div.textContent = myObj[key]` you're losing the previously assigned values.

A recommendation is to concatenate the previous values, for example:

```
div.textContent += separator + myObj[key]
```

Where `separator` could be `<br>`, `\n` or whatever string you think is suitable.

This is a sample of a response from `https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not looping well on the object here as you use for

You better use this syntax : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/keys

```
Object.keys(myObj).map((key) => {
    console.log(myObj[key], key)
}
```

or

```
Object.keys(myObj).map(function (key) {
    console.log(myObj[key], key)
}
```